# Codec to view .CR2 (canon raw) in Windows 10?

Tags: images, windows-10

I'd like to view .CR2 images in Windows 10. As a thumbnail in File Explorer, and in the Photos application.

Apparently I can ~"download the codec for Windows 8 and install in compatibility mode" but I'm not sure how to do that, or if there's an easier way.

Comment: .CR2 is not a single file format. Rather, it is a container format for [camera-specific data](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1455/1772). We may be able to give better recommendations if you tell us which camera model produced these files, or which camera models you need the utility to support.